# Possible to link to CSS file despite htaccess redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

This question has been asked before, but the answers posted don't seem to work for me. I hoping for some troubleshooting.

I have an .htaccess file to redirect ALL requests to my index.php file, with the request path stored as a variable. I want, however, to exclude a single directory (/admin/assets) from this process so that I can easily link to css files, etc.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^(assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above continues to redirect all traffic to the index.php file, but the linked-to CSS file (/admin/assets/main.css) is not loaded. What, if any, way is there around this?

Comment: so put in a rewritecond that matches/exempts css files... basically excactly what youv'e got with the `!^(assets)`, it'd just be `!\.css$`

Comment: @MarcB I tried this too - I'm getting a 500 error. Code is exactly as above.

Comment: that's because you're missing a space in your rewritecond. 500 errors have details about them in the server's error log. Anytime you get one you should check that error log FIRST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `%{REQUEST_URI}` contains `/admin/`, even if you set the `RewriteBase`.
Plus, you missed a space in your `RewriteCond`.

You need tu use this `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/assets
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```